# How do I fix zooming and panning in my cluster bundle graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming, drag

I've created a hierarchical edge bundling graph with some data and after trying to implement zooming and dragging on the graph I've run into some issues.

Here is a similar working jsfiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/hnjvxd48/1/

and the relevant code:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0,8])
    .on("zoom", zoomhandler);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("dragend", dragended);

var svg = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")
.call(zoom)
.call(drag);

function zoomhandler(){
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

You'll notice:

1) Dragging and zooming only occur on the outer edges and not the inner part of the graph.

2) Dragging the graph around causes flickering and centering of the graph to change and become cut off.

3) Zooming (done via mouse scroll wheel) also centers the graph incorrectly and places it in an unpredictable position, partly out of the view port.

4) Attempting to drag the graph after it has been zoomed out causes it to flicker and disappear.

What's causing these issues and how can I fix them? How can I give my graph (which is much bigger than the sample one I provided) an initially "zoomed out" state and perhaps trigger the zooming functionality using a button click event rather than the native scroll wheel implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big thing to notice here is that the drag functions are actually redundant. In this (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) d3 drag + zoom example, they're being used to move individual 'dots'. You want to move the whole graph at once, and this is handled by the 'translate' portion of the 'zoomhandler' function you've included.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/14f9f4k3/1/

And the key code that with changes noted in comments:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0,8])
    .on("zoom", zoomhandler);

//added another group as a child of the group having zoom called on it w/ id 'draggroup' to append nodes and links to 
var svg = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")
    .call(zoom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('id','draggroup');

//added a rect behind the other elements to make an easy target for the pointer
d3.select('#draggroup')
    .append('rect')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + -radius + "," + -radius + ")")
    .attr('width',diameter)
    .attr('height',diameter)
    .attr('fill','#fff');

//no need for separate drag functions, translate and scale here do what you want
function zoomhandler(){
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }

//append the links and nodes to the group we created above instead of the base svg
var link = d3.select('#draggroup').append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = d3.select('#draggroup').append("g").selectAll(".node");
```